# Looping through objects in JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, loops, firebase, for-loop

I have a JSON object like so:

```
{
  "workouts":
  [
    {
      "title": "Full Body",
      "exercises":
      [
        {
          "name": "Push Ups",
          "duration": 3,
          "break": 3
        },
        {
          "name": "Squats",
          "duration": 3,
          "break": 3
        },
        {
          "name": "Running in Place",
          "duration": 3,
          "break": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "God Legs",
      "exercises":
      [
        {
          "name": "Running in Place (High Knees)",
          "duration": 3,
          "break": 3
        },
        {
          "name": "Squats",
          "duration": 3,
          "break": 3
        },
        {
          "name": "Clams",
          "duration": 3,
          "break": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Morning Stretch",
      "exercises":
      [
        {
          "name": "Downward Dog",
          "duration": 3,
          "break": 3
        },
        {
          "name": "Face Plant",
          "duration": 3,
          "break": 3
        },
        {
          "name": "Warrior",
          "duration": 3,
          "break": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I can loop through the titles and append them to the body, now I would like to loop through each object contained in the "exercises" array and print out each value: name, duration and break, per object. I am not having much success and I wonder if I should change my JSON structure or if I am making some silly mistake in my loops. I am using Firebase by the way, no AJAX calls or such like.

JavaScript:

```
// Initialize firebase.
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child("workouts");

// Sync with Firebase in real time.
dbRef.on("value", snap =>
{
  var workouts = snap.val();

  // HAVE A LOOP FOR EVERY ARRAY INJSON.
  for (var i = 0;  i < workouts.length; i++)
  {
    window.alert(i + workouts[i].title); // Works fine.

    var obj = workouts[i].exercises;
    for (obj in workouts)
    {
      alert(obj.name); // Returns undefined for each object.
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Remove `var obj = workouts[i].exercises;` and replace `for (obj in workouts)` with `for (obj in workouts[i].exercises)`. You're overwriting the `obj` variable and looping over the wrong array unless I'm misstaken.

Comment: Doing UI based on JSON objects is so nice with something like [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io/) btw. Just an aside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `for..in` to iterate through arrays generally isn't a great idea in JS. Try using [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to go through all items in the array instead:

```
var obj = workouts[i].exercises;
obj.forEach(function(exercise) {
    alert(exercise.name);
});
```

Comment: That is great! Thank you! I was looking through forEach docs online, but being a n00b was kinda lost in how to use them correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var obj = workouts[i].exercises;
for (index in obj) {
    console.log(obj[index].name);
}
```

It's a bit of logical fault here. You want to get the `exercise` name, not the `workout` name.

Answer (score 1):

As long as more modern JS is ok, I would probably suggest you use [`array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) with a callback in both of your loops.

```js
const data = {"workouts":[{"title":"Full Body","exercises":[{"name":"Push Ups","duration":3,"break":3},{"name":"Squats","duration":3,"break":3},{"name":"Running in Place","duration":3,"break":3}]},{"title":"God Legs","exercises":[{"name":"Running in Place (High Knees)","duration":3,"break":3},{"name":"Squats","duration":3,"break":3},{"name":"Clams","duration":3,"break":3}]},{"title":"Morning Stretch","exercises":[{"name":"Downward Dog","duration":3,"break":3},{"name":"Face Plant","duration":3,"break":3},{"name":"Warrior","duration":3,"break":3}]}]}

data.workouts.forEach(workout => {
  workout.exercises.forEach(exercise => console.log(workout.title, '---', exercise.name));
});
```

For more backwards compatibility you could do nested loops like so:

```js
const data = {"workouts":[{"title":"Full Body","exercises":[{"name":"Push Ups","duration":3,"break":3},{"name":"Squats","duration":3,"break":3},{"name":"Running in Place","duration":3,"break":3}]},{"title":"God Legs","exercises":[{"name":"Running in Place (High Knees)","duration":3,"break":3},{"name":"Squats","duration":3,"break":3},{"name":"Clams","duration":3,"break":3}]},{"title":"Morning Stretch","exercises":[{"name":"Downward Dog","duration":3,"break":3},{"name":"Face Plant","duration":3,"break":3},{"name":"Warrior","duration":3,"break":3}]}]};

for (let i = 0, len = data.workouts.length; i < len; i++) {
  let exercises = data.workouts[i].exercises;
  for (let x = 0, l = exercises.length; x < l; x++) {
    console.log(data.workouts[i].title, '---', data.workouts[i].exercises[x].name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried to write solution with just **map()** operator

```js
var mainObj = {
  "workouts":
  [
{
  "title": "Full Body",
  "exercises":
  [
    {
      "name": "Push Ups",
      "duration": 3,
      "break": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "Squats",
      "duration": 3,
      "break": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "Running in Place",
      "duration": 3,
      "break": 3
    }
  ]
},
{
  "title": "God Legs",
  "exercises":
  [
    {
      "name": "Running in Place (High Knees)",
      "duration": 3,
      "break": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "Squats",
      "duration": 3,
      "break": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "Clams",
      "duration": 3,
      "break": 3
    }
  ]
},
{
  "title": "Morning Stretch",
  "exercises":
  [
    {
      "name": "Downward Dog",
      "duration": 3,
      "break": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "Face Plant",
      "duration": 3,
      "break": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "Warrior",
      "duration": 3,
      "break": 3
    }
  ]
}
  ]
}

mainObj["workouts"].map(obj => obj["exercises"].map(exercises => console.log(obj["title"]+"-->"+exercises["name"])))
```

Comment: That is quite awesome!

Comment: You can also use "dot notation" so you can use autocompletion properties:
mainObj.workouts.map(obj => obj.exercises.map(exercises => console.log(obj.title+"-->"+exercises.name)))